# Is it possible to create MS Office add-in for Windows Store in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, windows-store-apps, office-addins

I have this simple question: Is it possible to create MS Office add-in for Windows Store in Delphi?

Rati

Comment: These people should know about the Windows Store aspect:https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-delphi/index.php

Comment: I already checked this issue with add-in-express. They do not support the Windows Store.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to create a MS Office add-in with Delphi, but you can't publish it within the Microsoft Store (Windows Store).

The option isn't available to publish MS Office add-ins on the Microsoft Store.

As MartinA mentioned in the comments. You can also use [Add-In Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-delphi/index.php) to develop MS Office add-ins with Delphi VCL.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, but  Add-In Express  does not support Windows Store.

Comment: From what Shaun said, it's the other way around.

Comment: @Rati2019 Yes, because you can not publish MS Office Add-ins on the Microsoft Store (Windows Store). That is not possible.

Comment: It is possible to publish MS Office Add-ins in AppStore, here is the instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/use-the-seller-dashboard-to-submit-to-the-office-store.